# Javascript - reloading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I use javascript to avoid reloading content on website all over again(a lot of flash content). And I meet problem that using this script when I want to put another flash content under link which is using this script my flash gallery is not starting.

This is script I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#content').load('content/blank.php');

    $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
        });

});
```

I think if there is possibility to refresh subwebsite one at start and avoid to reload all site but I dont have idea how to make it.

Thanks for respond.

Comment: I think the best option would be to avoid Flash content all together ?

Comment: Anything on the JavaScript console? If you try to load the content directly (using curl) does it work?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. To be clear, you're using jQueries .load method to load content, you then want to refresh that same content? What do you mean when you say 'sub website'? Can you link us to the page?

Comment: problem is when I use normal url website is reloading so header which is all in flash - reloading everytime I click link. To avoid that I use JS but problem is that when I want put galery in flash+js - its show me black screen - I figure that maybe in this way animation not recive signal to start = maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure 

link: http://alphatest.cba.pl/

gallery is under "Links"